# Designing Javascript Hangman guessing game for my homework assignment but can't get code to work

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm trying to design this hangman game for my coding boot camp, and I thought I got everything to function... but it looks like every single time I've tried running my code, it doesn't work. Specifically, the letters will not show up onto the page (which is the whole point of the hangman game). (I'm extremely new to coding, so I'm sorry if I'm not making much sense... or if my code is a hot mess).

I'm not quite sure if I'm console logging everything properly. I feel like I probably have a lot of errors that are not all being called when I go into the console. I don't think the letters are being called on, but I'm not quite sure how to change it.

```
// My list of favorite 90s shows ... and their word options
var words = ["Sister Sister", "Saved by the Bell", "Family Matters", "All That", "Friends", "The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air"]
var letter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "-", "_"];

// game counters 
var blanks = 0; // blanks
var wins = 0; // number of wins 
var losses = 0; // number of losess
var maxGuesses = 10; // how many guesses the player has
var guessesRemaining = 0; // how many guesses are remaining 

// players guesses 
var blanksLetters = []; // both blank and solved letters
var guessedLetters = []; // stores guessed letters
var wrongGuesses = []; // stores wrong guesses
var ansWordArr = [];
var ansWord = "";

// the token booleans
isFinished = true; 
letterInWord = true;

setup();

// other important functionality for keys
document.onkeyup = function(event) { // captures key clicks
    // Converts all key clicks to uppercase letters... because that's more FUN.
    var guessedLetters = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toUpperCase();

    // Runs the code to check for correctness.
    checkGuess(letter);


};

/**
 * Helper functions
 */
// start game 
function setup() {

    // start game
    maxGuesses = 10;

    // word is randomly chosen from the list
    ansWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

    // split word into individual letters
    ansWordArr = ansWord.split("");

    // count number of letters in word
    blanks = ansWordArr.length;

    // adds "_" to blanks ... here's my for loop
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) { 
        blanksLetters.push("_");
    }

    // resetting after rounds
    blanksLetters = [];
    gessesRemaining = maxGuesses; 
    guessedLetters = [];
    wrongGuesses = []; 

    // testing
    console.log(ansWord); // to print word in console 
    console.log(blanksLetters); // to print blanks in console

    // to warn the player of running out of guesses
    document.getElementById("numGuesses").style.color = "";

    //show the selected elements on the screen 
    updateScreen();

    // display gifs of shows 
    document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "";
};

 // updating HTML 
 function updateScreen() {
    document.getElementById("wins").innerText = wins; // prints wins, restarts game
    document.getElementById("losses").innerText = losses; // prints losses, restarts game
    document.getElementById("guesses").innerText = guessesRemaining; // prints guesses left
    document.getElementById("ansWord").innerText = ansWordArr.join(""); // prints blanks and guesses 
    document.getElementById("wrongGuesses").innerText = wrongGuesses.join(""); // prints incorrect letters
    document.getElementById("guessedLetters").innerText = guessedLetters; // prints guessed letters
};

// check for winners 
function winner() {
    // add +1 to the player's score, given that there's no more "_" in ansWord.
    if (ansWordArr.toString() === guessedLetters.toString()) {
        wins++;
        alert("BOO-YAH!!!");
        isFinished = true;

        // if answer is correct, play gif of that show 
        if(ansWord === "Sister Sister") {
            document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/RxyLmP3eQyCvS/html5";
        }
        else if(ansWord === "Saved By the Bell") {
            document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/1HPzxMBCTvjMs/html5";
        }
        else if(ansWord === "Family Matters") {
            document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/3o85g8TYvayD4rhj9u/html5";
        }
        else if(ansWord === "All That") {
            document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/l4Ep1CAHPrPAEe1So/html5";
        }
        else if(ansWord === "Friends") {
            document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/C4msBrFb6szHG/html5";
        }
        else if(ansWord === "The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air") {
            document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/Mxygn6lbNmh20/html5";
        }
    };
};

// key activity 
function checkGuess(letter) {

    // current state
    var letterInWord = false;

    // If letter is in the word
    // if (letterInWord) {
        for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
            if (ansWord[i] === letter) {
                letterInWord = true;
                blanksLetters[i] = letter;
            }
        }
    // }

    if (!letterInWord) {
        wrongGuesses.push(letter);
        maxGuesses--; 
    };
    console.log(letterInWord);
    console.log(blanksLetters);

}; 

// check for losers 
function loser() {
    // if guessesRemaining = 0, add +1 to losses
    if (maxGuesses === 0) {
        losses++;
        alert("As If!");
        isFinished = true;

        //play the loser gif
        document.getElementById("giphy-embed").src = "https://giphy.com/gifs/3og0IEeKFFlzaykixW/html5";
        document.getElementById("losses").style.color = "#FF0000";
    }
};
```

I expect letters to show up on the page when I'm making guesses.

Comment: share your html code as well

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: You call `letter`(array) as parameter to `checkGuess` when you should pass a guess (`guessedLetters` (character) )

Answer (score 1):

#### Some correction

First of all, booleans are also variables, so they should be declared properly:

```js
// the token booleans
let isFinished = true; 
let letterInWord = true;
```

It is advised to use [ECMAScript6](http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedVariables) specification, so use `const` for constant values and `let` for variables instead of using the old `var` keyword.

A blank string doesn't make too much sense to css:

```js
// to warn the player of running out of guesses
document.getElementById("numGuesses").style.color = "white";
```

#### Problems

The `letter` variable is an array and after in call of `checkGuess(letter)` you compare an array with a character:

```js
let letter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "-", "_"]
.
.
.
if (ansWord[i] === letter) {
   letterInWord = true;
   blanksLetters[i] = letter;
}
```

You never call `winners()` or `losers()`.

#### Suggestions

1. Show us the HTML code of this game.
2. Change the `checkGuess(letter)` to `checkGuess("A")` or some other letter and see what happens.
3. Do

```js
console.log('\nloser');
loser();
console.log('\nwinner');
winner();
```

After `updateScreen()` in the `setup()` function and see what happens.

Comment: And btw. we live in ES6 world. We should use `let` to not get confused with [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. Your example does not have a html, which is bad for some, if it is clearly a JS problem, why not just ignore them? Especially because they just show us the values to screen so `console.log()` or `document.write()` should work the same.

I cannot see any occurence of `winners()` or `losers()` and no occurence of `updateScreen()` after `checkGuess()`, so maybe there lays the problem with letters not showing up. Also `checkGuess` seems a bit odd for me, but will check it out alone and say in a moment.

So... In setup you call

```
// adds "_" to blanks ... here's my for loop
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) { 
        blanksLetters.push("_");
    }

    // resetting after rounds
    blanksLetters = [];
```

Which sets blankLetters to array of "_"s and then you delete everything with `blankLetters = [];`. That makes no sense.

Then you use `blankLetters` in `checkGuess`, but that's okay, because you donot try to read from it. Just saves to it. And that's why this seems so odd for me. But that's okay.

I ran this code (shortened version of yours code):

```
let wrongGuesses = [];
let maxGuesses = 10;
let ansWord = "TenLetters";
let blanks = andWord.length;
let blanksLetters = [];
function checkGuess(letter) {
    // current state
    var letterInWord = false;

    // If letter is in the word
    // if (letterInWord) {
        for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
            if (ansWord[i].toUpperCase() === letter.toUpperCase()) {
                letterInWord = true;
                blanksLetters[i] = letter;
            }
        }
    // }

    if (!letterInWord) {
        wrongGuesses.push(letter);
        maxGuesses--; 
    };
    console.log(letterInWord);
    console.log(blanksLetters);

};
```

I had to add `.toUpperCase()` in your if statement, because you forgot to do that.
And when you call `checkGuess(letter)` in onkeyup you send an entire array and not a guess. Change it to `checkGuess(guessedLetter)`.
And made a guess as if I clicked "e" on keyboard:

```
checkGuess("E");
```

And it worked. Logs were:

```
true
Array(8) [ <1 empty slot>, "e", <2 empty slots>, "e", <2 empty slots>, "e" ]
```

Snippet:

```js
let wrongGuesses = [];
let maxGuesses = 10;
let ansWord = "TenLetters";
let blanks = ansWord.length;
let blanksLetters = [];
function checkGuess(letter) {
// current state
var letterInWord = false;

// If letter is in the word
// if (letterInWord) {
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
        if (ansWord[i].toUpperCase() === letter.toUpperCase()) {
            letterInWord = true;
            blanksLetters[i] = letter;
        }
    }
// }

if (!letterInWord) {
    wrongGuesses.push(letter);
    maxGuesses--; 
};
console.log(letterInWord);
console.log(blanksLetters);

};
checkGuess("E")
```